# Считывание данных из файла ПОСЛЕ выхода из программы

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
// 7_классы ф2.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo> //вкл RTTI

using namespace std;

const int LEN = 32; //длина фамилии
//const int MAX=100; // число работников
enum eEmployee {tmanager,tscientist,tlaborer};

class cEmployee{
    char name[LEN]; 
    int number; 
    static int n;
    static const int MAX = 100;
    //enum{ MAX = 100 };
    static cEmployee* arr[MAX];
public:
    virtual void get(){ cout << "Enter name: "; cin >> name; cout << "Enter num: "; cin >> number; }
    virtual void show(){ cout << name << '\t' << number << '\t'; }
    virtual eEmployee get_type();

    static void add();
    static void display();
    static void read();
    static void write();
};
int cEmployee::n;
cEmployee* cEmployee::arr[MAX];

class cManager :public cEmployee{
    char title[LEN];
    double dues;
public:
    void get(){ cEmployee::get(); cout << "Enter title: "; cin >> title; cout << "Enter tax: "; cin >> dues; }
    void show(){ cEmployee::show(); cout << title << '\t' << dues << '\n'; }
};
class cScientist :public cEmployee{
    int pubs;
public:
    void get(){ cEmployee::get(); cout << "Enter pubs: "; cin >> pubs;  }
    void show(){ cEmployee::show(); cout << " Pubs:"<<pubs << '\n'; }
};
class cLaborer :public cEmployee
    {
    };

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char ch;
    while (true){
        cout << "\n'a' - to add info about employee\n"
            << "'d' - to display all employees\n"
            << "'w' - to write all data into file\n"
            << "'r' - to read all data from file\n"
            << "'x' - for exit \n";
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch){
        case 'a':cEmployee::add(); break;
        case 'd':cEmployee::display(); break;
        case 'w':cEmployee::write(); break;
        case 'r':cEmployee::read(); break;
        case 'x':exit(0);
        default: cout << "Unknown comand!\n";
        }
    }
    _gettch();
    return 0;
}
void cEmployee::write(){
    cout << "Recording of " << n << " people.\n";
    ofstream out("Emp.dat", ios::trunc| ios::binary);
    if (!out) { cout << "Error to open\n"; return; }

    int size;
    eEmployee etemp;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        etemp = arr[i]->get_type(); //тип нашего объекта, кто он: ученый, менеджер?
        out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&etemp), sizeof(etemp));  // запись 0,1 или 2 (тип работника)
        switch (etemp){
        case tmanager: size = sizeof(cManager); break;
        case tscientist: size = sizeof(cScientist); break;
        case tlaborer: size = sizeof(cLaborer); break;
        }
        out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(arr[i]), size);//запись других полей
        if (!out) { cerr << "Error to record\n"; return; }
    }
}
void cEmployee::read(){
    ifstream in("Emp.dat", ios::binary);
    if (!in) { cerr << "Error to open\n"; return; }

    eEmployee etemp;
    int size;

    //in.seekg(0);
    n = 0;
    while (true){
        in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&etemp), sizeof(etemp));
        if (in.eof()) break;
        if (!in) { cerr << "Error to read\n"; return; }
        switch (etemp){
        case tmanager:
            arr[n] = new cManager;
            size = sizeof(cManager);
            break;
        case tscientist:
            arr[n] = new cScientist;
            size = sizeof(cScientist);
            break;
        case tlaborer:
            arr[n] = new cLaborer;
            size = sizeof(cLaborer);
            break;
        default:cerr << "Unknown type in the file!\n"; return; 
        }
        in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(arr[n]), size);
        if (!in) { cerr << "Error to read\n"; return; }
        n++;
    }
    cout << "Reading of " << n << " people.\n";
}
eEmployee cEmployee::get_type(){
    if (typeid(*this) == typeid(cManager)) return tmanager;
    else if (typeid(*this) == typeid(cScientist)) return tscientist;
    else if (typeid(*this) == typeid(cLaborer)) return tlaborer;
    else { cerr << "\nError"; exit(1); }
    return tmanager;
}
void cEmployee::add(){
    char ch;
    cout << "'m' for manager\n"
        << "'s' for scientist\n"
        << "'l' for laborer\n"
        << "Enter: ";
    cin >> ch;
    switch (ch){
    case 'm': arr[n] = new cManager; break;//создание ОБЪЕКТА
    case 's': arr[n] = new cScientist; break;
    case 'l': arr[n] = new cLaborer; break;
    default:cout << "\nUnknow employee.\n "; return;
    }
    arr[n++]->get();
}
void cEmployee::display(){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << i + 1;
        switch (arr[i]->get_type()){   //ошибка!
        case tmanager: cout << ". Type: Manager "; break;
        case tscientist: cout << ". Type: Scientist "; break;
        case tlaborer: cout << ". Type: Laborer "; break;
        default:cout << "\nUnknow employee.\n "; 
        }
        arr[i]->show();   //ошибка!
    }
}
```

1. Если ввести работников; `write()` их в файл; `read()` их из файла; `display()`, то все хорошо 
2. Если закрыть программу; запустить и сразу считать: `read()` из файла, то при выводе `display()` возникает ошибка обращения объекта к методам:
 `arr[i]->get_type();` или `arr[i]->show();` - как будто я не создал объекта! хотя в `read()` я это делаю с помощью `arr[n] = new cManager;`

При отладке тоже видно, что объекты инициализируются данными из файла. Но если объекты, а точнее указатели на них, обращаются к методам, то возникает ошибка "нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что Вы записываете ***экземпляры классов*** в файл со всеми их служебными данными:

```
out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(arr[i]), size);//запись других полей
```

Экземпляры классов в *C++* в общем случае не являются POD-типами (Plain Old Data, простая структура данных) и хранят некую служебную информацию, например, указатель на VMT (Virtual Methods Table - таблица виртуальных методов). Соответственно, при чтении из файла выстроенная компилятором тонкая структура экземпляра класса и его работа нарушаются, что приводит к неопределённому поведению программы.

В таких случаях нужно писать в файл не класс целиком, а его поля по отдельности.

Comment: Может тогда стоит хранить поля в struct?

Comment: `struct` в *C++* - это `class` с `public` по умолчанию. Можно, но надо очень осторожно. `struct` является POD не всегда.

Comment: @JK_Action Это ничего не меняет, если среди полей будут что-то нетривиальное - например, `string`, или те же виртуальные функции.

Comment: @Harry про string не подумал. А виртуальные функции в strucrt это сильно.

Comment: @JK_Action А что тут такого?:) как справедливо замечено, `struct` не более чем сокращение для `class { public:` Код `struct Test {
    virtual ~Test(){}
};` вполне компилируем и работоспособен...

Comment: @Harry но все мы прекрасно понимаем, что так делать не стоит. Я как-то у Алены С++ спрашивал зачем использовать struct вместо класса, она высказала мнение, что struct логически не предполагает наследования.

Comment: @JK_Action Конечно. Правила хорошего тона (читай - стиля) программирования по сути говорят о том, что `struct` надо использовать только для POD, но ведь _следует использовать_ и _нельзя использовать иначе как_ - две большие разницы. Т.е. главное, что слово `struct` не говорит в плане того, что именно оно означает - POD, что-то ужасно нетривиальное или даже виртуальное - *абсолютно ничего*.

Answer (score 4):

Ваши работники в программном отношении вовсе не то, что называют Plain Old Data, и с ними нельзя обращаться так сурово - просто брать и сбрасывать их в файл, передавая адрес на начало объекта. И уж совершенно категорически это не следует делать при наличии виртуальных функций - потому что в этом случае как минимум у объекта есть еще указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций, который вы благополучно затираете при чтении. Пока вы еще в пределах выполнения одной программы - он случайно :) затирается собой же, а вот если считывание заново... Он указывает куда-то в непонятное место, и все вызовы виртуальных функций адресуются в неизвестное место.

Посмотрите в сам файл - у вас там явно будут как минимум лишние 4 байта этого самого указателя.

Так что пусть класс сам пишет-читает данные по полям - так надежнее всего.