# Чтение и запись в файл c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, файлы, наследование, полиморфизм

Есть 2 класса, один наследуется от другого, причем базовый класс содержит хотя бы 1 виртуальный метод.

При первом запуске программы я записываю в файл в бинарном виде экземпляр наследуемого класса и при повторном запуске программы я пытаюсь считать из файла обратно в объект. Если не использовать полиморфизм, то есть не создавать виртуальные функции в базовом классе, то все работает нормально, в другом случае программа крашится, пишет obj-> было 0x..... ,посмотрев в отладчике я заметил что чтение памяти из _vfptr невозможно, вот и задаюсь вопросом, как это можно обойти.

```
class B {
public:
    B() {}
    float f;
    virtual void printf() = 0;
};

class A : public B {
public:
    int a;
    char k;
    A() {
        f = 2;
        a = 1111;
        k = '?';
    }
    void printf() {
        cout << a << endl << k << endl << f << endl << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A *obj = new A();
    FILE* file;
    int t = 1;//(после 1 запуска программы меняю значение на 2 и повторно запускаю)
    if (t == 1) {
        file = fopen("file.dat", "w+b");
        fwrite(obj, sizeof(obj), 1, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else if (t == 2) {
        file = fopen("file.dat", "r+b");
        fread(obj, sizeof(obj), 1, file);
        fclose(file);
        obj->printf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете посмотреть на полный код в моем дополненном ответе...

Answer (score 2):

Прямая запись нетривиальных объектов в бинарный файл как "сырых" бинарных данных возможна только в контексте одной программной сессии. Т.е. фактически такой подход жизнеспособен только если вы реализуете некое подобие своего собственного временного "своп файла".

Пытаться использовать такой способ сохранения данных *между* программными сессиями ("при повторном запуске программы...") обречены на провал.

Чтобы выполнить сохранение, живущее между программными сессиями, вам придется самостоятельно разработать некий формат/протокол (возможно, весьма нетривиальный), который позволит вам сериализовать те свойства ваших данных, которые впрямую в файл записать нельзя: значения указателей, типы полиморфных объектов и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Вещи, которые не являются plain old data, нельзя просто писать на диск и считывать как единое целое. Даже если внутри класса нет указателей на какие-то данные, у вас есть указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций. Пока вы в пределах одного выполнения, указатели еще сохраняются, так что возможно чтение-запись, но в разных...

Заведите функции записи и чтения **членов-данных**, а не всего объекта в целом.

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/617451/195342), [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615690/195342) или [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/495227/195342) я уже отвечал на подобные вопросы, можете посмотреть.

Вот вам код, как это делать *правильно*.

```
class B {
public:
    B() {}
    float f;
    virtual void printf() = 0;
    virtual void write(FILE* fl)
    {
        fwrite(&f,sizeof(f),1,fl);
    }
    virtual void read(FILE* fl)
    {
        fread(&f,sizeof(f),1,fl);
    }
};

class A : public B {
public:
    int a;
    char k;
    A() {
        f = 2;
        a = 1111;
        k = '?';
    }
    void printf() {
        cout << a << endl << k << endl << f << endl << endl;
    }
    virtual void write(FILE* fl)
    {
        B::write(fl);
        fwrite(&a,sizeof(a),1,fl);
        fwrite(&k,sizeof(k),1,fl);
    }
    virtual void read(FILE* fl)
    {
        B::read(fl);
        fread(&a,sizeof(a),1,fl);
        fread(&k,sizeof(k),1,fl);
    }
};

int main() {
    A *obj = new A();
    FILE* file;
    int t = 1;//(после 1 запуска программы меняю значение на 2 и повторно запускаю)
    if (t == 1) {
        file = fopen("file.dat", "w+b");
        obj->write(file);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else if (t == 2) {
        file = fopen("file.dat", "r+b");
        obj->read(file);
        fclose(file);
        obj->printf();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как любитель нестандартных выстрелов в ногу я не мог пройти мимо.
Рабочее решение найти удалось, вот кусок кода:

```
int main()
{
    A *obj = new A();
    FILE* file;
    int t = 2;//(после 1 запуска программы меняю значение на 2 и повторно запускаю)
    if (t == 1) 
    {
        file = fopen("file.dat", "w+b");
        // Обратите внимание, в оригинале у вас тут написано sizeof(obj), но obj - это указатель, а его размер всегда 4 (или 8) байт
        // надо писать либо sizeof(A) либо sizeof(*obj), чтобы получить реальный размер занятой памяти
        fwrite(obj, sizeof(A), 1, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
    else if (t == 2) 
    {
        A* donor = new A(); // Донор нам нужен для копирования __vfptr 
        A* obj2 = new A();  // Объект, куда читаем из файла
        A* obj3 = new A();  // Объект, который будет создан по данным, считанным из файла
        memset(obj2, 0, sizeof(A)); // Для чистоты эксперимента вся память зануляется
        memset(obj3, 0, sizeof(A));
        // Читаем из файла в obj2
        file = fopen("file.dat", "r+b");
        fread(obj2, sizeof(A), 1, file);
        fclose(file);
        // После чтения из файла мы получили obj2 с невалидным __vfptr, копируем целиком всю память в obj3
        memcpy(obj3, obj2, sizeof(A));
        // Копируем для obj3 валидный __vfptr из экземпляра-донора
        memcpy(obj3, donor, sizeof(void*));

        // И оно работает (по крайней мере у меня)
        obj3->printf();
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет никакой гарантии, что указатель на vtable находится со смещением 0, нет никакой гарантии, что в классе имеется только он, а не еще что-то... Воистину, стрельба в ногу, только еще и из пулемета :)